# Text area replacing a link when clicking on that link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to do exactly the same thing as the "add comment" effect on stackoverflow. I have found a lot of information on how to open a text area (but it is a pop up) when the user click on a link (or a button), but I do not find a way to do this :

When the user click on "Inscription by email"

```
<div class="end-right-zone">
    <p>Inscription by e-mail</p>
</div>
```

The zone is replaced by the various information required to register by email :

```
<div class="inscription-by-email-deployed">
    <p>first name</p>
    <p>last name</p>
    <p>email</p>
</div>
```

I do not develop to much the example, as it is exactly the same as the "add comment" effect on stackoverflow. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want something like this, perhaps (using jQuery)?

```
$(".end-right-zone p").click(function() {
    $(".end-right-zone").html($(".inscription-by-email-deployed").html());
});
```

Or, in the event that you wanted to *replace* `.end-right-zone` entirely, try something like this:

```
$(".end-right-zone p").click(function() {
    $(".end-right-zone").replaceWith($(".inscription-by-email-deployed"));
});
```

Comment: that will **embed** `.inscription-by-email-deployed` element inside `.end-right-zone` and not replace it...

Comment: I assumed that's what he wanted, but I'll edit just in case you're right.

Comment: This look excellent thank you, I am trying it (to include it in my real case is a little more complex and I am not an expert in this domain so it will take some time but I'll let you know ;) )

Comment: It's perfect, I just had to add :

Comment: $(".inscription-by-email-deployed").attr('style', 'display:block');

Comment: in order to display the block (css attribute before : "display:none;"). Thanks a lot !

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help.